# Помогите сделать правильно присваивание

Tags: php

Хочу присвоить значения из бд

```
$bdir= $myrow2["link_b"];

$dir =  $myrow2["link"];
```

в линках ссылки на папки
но как не пытаюсь присвоить значения постоянно `$bdir` и `$dir` пусты:(что делать?

```
 echo $myrow2["link_b"];

 echo $myrow2["link"]; //- вывод данных происходит
```

полный код

```
<?php include("blocks/bd.php");?>
<?php include 'css/functions.php';?>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {$id = $_GET['cat'];}
if(!isset ($id)) {$id=1;}
/* Проверяем, является ли переменная числом */
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
exit ("<p>Неверный формат запроса! Проверьте URL!");
}
$result2 =mysql_query("SELECT link,link_b FROM cat WHERE id='$id'",$bd);
if(!$result2)
{
    echo"<p>Запрос на выборку из базы данных НЕ прошел!!!...Сообщите Админенстратору admin@r.com <br><strong>Код ошибки:</strong></p>";
    exit (mysql_error());
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0)
{
$myrow2= mysql_fetch_array($result2);
 echo $myrow2["link_b"];
 echo $myrow2["link"];
}
else
{
    echo"<p>Информация по запросу НЕ может быть извлечина!...В таблице нет записей</p>";
    exit();
    };
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title><?php echo $myrow2["title"];?></title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style_left.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style_img.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $myrow2["meta_k"];?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $myrow2["meta_d"];?>">
</head>

<body>
<table width="1150px" align="center">
  <tr>
   <?php include("blocks/header.php");?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" align="left">
      <tr>
     <?php include("blocks/left.php");?>
     <?php include("blocks/right.php");?>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <?php include("blocks/footer.php");?>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

потом это этот блок

 <td width="950px" valign="top">
<?php 
$bdir=echo $myrow2["link_b"];
$dir=echo $myrow2["link"];
$images=get_images($dir);

?>
 <td>
 <div class="wripper">
     <div class="gallery">
<?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
 <div class="item">
            <div>
                <a data-lightbox="lightbox" href="<?=$bdir .$image?>"> 
                <img class="front" src="<?=$dir .$image?>" alt="" >
                </a>
             </div>
             </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>          
    </div>
 </div>
 </td>
 </td>
```

Comment: Либо из базы ничего не возвращается, либо неправильно заносите данные в массив. Приведите полный код программы.

Comment: Э... На словах "Админенстратору" и "извлечина" захотелось тут же закрыть окно и куда-нибудь убежать...

Comment: Дело не в ошибках(я редактирую)синтаксисом в конце займусь

Answer (score 1):

Вы же сами понимаете, что чудес на свете не бывает. Есть масса способов проверить

1. Попробуй там где ты в дальнейшем пользуешься `$bdir, $dir подставь $myrow2["link_b"]б $myrow2["link"]` соответственно
2. Говоришь, что значения вытягиваются из бд, так вот и выполни запрос на мускульном клиенте и просмотри нет ли там пустых значений по этим двум полям
3. Отдебаж в шторме(раставь дампы)